# ShareKit facebook, view disappear after loggin, dont display link in dialog window

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

I am trying to add ShareKit 2.0 in my app (with ARC), Xcode 3.2 and device 4.x or 5.0,

I have followed ALL configuration steps from  https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit

In the app when I click on "Facebook" button to share, I get loggin OK, but once I do loggin the view disappear and it does not nothing more.

It doesn't display link in dialog window.

Any idea?